# My SWT label is not changing text with the selection of new item in combobox?

Tags: java, label, swt, refresh

I am currently using absolute layout and I have a label which is supposed to change as a new item is selected in the combo box I made it work with grid layout but this messes with other functions, buttons and labels I have how would I make this work for me... anything would be appreciated..
this is the part of the code i am talking about:

```
    Combo comboLevels = new Combo(shellAfterCasual, SWT.NONE);
    comboLevels.setBounds(10, 40, 91, 23);
    String[] item = new String[] { "Swedish 1", "Swedish 2", "Swedish 3" };
    comboLevels.setItems(new String[] {"Swedish 1", "Swedish 2", "Swedish 3"});
    comboLevels.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
             levelStr1 = comboLevels.getItem(comboLevels.getSelectionIndex());
            System.out.println("Selection: " + comboLevels.getItem(comboLevels.getSelectionIndex()));


            Label lblvarLvlLabel = new Label(shellAfterCasual, SWT.NONE);
            lblvarLvlLabel.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 12, SWT.BOLD | SWT.ITALIC));
            lblvarLvlLabel.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_INFO_BACKGROUND));
            lblvarLvlLabel.setBounds(145, 5, 107, 27);
            lblvarLvlLabel.setText(comboLevels.getText());
            lblvarLvlLabel.getParent().layout();
            /*'''''''''''''.............'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''*/
            System.out.println("XDDD;"+levelStr1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Basically I want the label to have Swedish 1 or 2 or 3respectiveley to what is selected

Comment: and it is updating it only once for example if swedish 1 is selected swedish 1 will appear but it will not change ifswedish 2 or 3 is selectd after that

Comment: What is JComboBox doing in there, that is Swing not SWT. You are creating a new Label every time the selection changed - not good. Trying to use mix setBounds with Layouts won't work properly.

Comment: I dont think it is a JcomboBox i am using the window builder and it is not the JFace option...

Comment: the JCombo box isnt supposed to be there i realised

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out how to do this i initiated the label outside the action listener so that the label is always there but it .setText and .updates when the item is selected as such:

```
Label lblvarLvlLabel = new Label(shellAfterCasual, SWT.NONE);
    lblvarLvlLabel.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 12, SWT.BOLD | SWT.ITALIC));
    lblvarLvlLabel.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_INFO_BACKGROUND));
    lblvarLvlLabel.setBounds(145, 5, 107, 27);


    Combo comboLevels = new Combo(shellAfterCasual, SWT.NONE);
    comboLevels.setBounds(10, 40, 91, 23);
    String[] item = new String[] { "Swedish 1", "Swedish 2", "Swedish 3" };
    comboLevels.setItems(new String[] {"Swedish 1", "Swedish 2", "Swedish 3"});
    comboLevels.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
             levelStr1 = comboLevels.getItem(comboLevels.getSelectionIndex());
            System.out.println("Selection: " + comboLevels.getItem(comboLevels.getSelectionIndex()));
            lblvarLvlLabel.setText(comboLevels.getText());
            lblvarLvlLabel.getParent().layout();
            lblvarLvlLabel.redraw();
            lblvarLvlLabel.update();
        }
    });
```